# node express http(s) server custom url

Tags: node.js, http, express

I know to build a basic HTTP server in Node with Express, all I need is this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(1234);
console.log('HTTP server listening on port: $d',server.address().port);
```

And then I can:

```
curl http://123.45.67.89:1234
```

and get a reponse back.

My question: instead of the URL:PORT being my homepage, is it a domain controller or my node/express application that allows my home page to be:

```
http://mywebsite
```

or

```
http://mywebsite/somestuff
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: you  should create A record of your domain to point to your public ip address and change `server.listen(1234);` to `server.listen(80);` as your meaning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short answer

You need to buy a web server with the domain name "mywebsite". So it is controlled by the domain controller.

### The long answer

"*http://*" is obviously the protocol being used by the server.

"*mywebsite*" is your website domain name and is **not** controlled by node.

"*.com*" is the top-level domain also **not** controlled by node.

"*/somestuff*" is controlled by node.

So to get a website that looks like this http://mywebsite.com/somestuff.
You need to buy the domain "mywebsite" and choose the top-level domain "com", this can be done from any company offering web servers. The only thing you can control with node is "/somestuff". Everything after the domain name and top-level domain is controlled by you directly so it can be changed easy. The other stuff cant be changed after you bought the server. Well it can but then you have to buy a new domain....

Comment: Shoot!  Carl, thank you for the answer.  I realize I poorly phrased my question.  I apologize for that, and am going to make an edit.

Comment: Just edited my answer in response to your comment. Hope this is what you are looking for. @westandy

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  I can talk with my customer at some point, but it looks like we will be living with the basic IP:PORT for now.  Thanks, @Carl. O!

Comment: It's worth noting that most websites don't need the :port part because they use port 80, which is what the browser uses by default. In order for node to bind port 80, it will need to run as root, or, more commonly, you bind to some other port, and then use nginx as a **reverse proxy** (look that up).

Comment: @Madara Uchiha - thanks for the information.  I'll talk with my crew about that, and see what we can/can't do.  We are not on the "open web" which makes things easy sometimes, and impossible other times.

Comment: Whether or not your hostname points at a public address or not, what I said still applies. Up to you though